# Windows 7: Server disappearing from Network window

Tags: windows-7, networking, windows-server-2003

I am running a small (three computer) network on a Windows Server 2003 domain. All of the computers were just upgraded to Windows 7. Since the upgrade, the icon for the domain server periodically disappears from the Network window on all three computers. It doesn't happen at the same time on all computers--the icon typically disappears from one machine, but not the others. And it's not always the same computer. The network connection is still there--I can type `\\myserver` and get to the network shares. It's simply the icon that's disappearing.

Any suggestions for a fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would look to DNS.

Is the Windows Server 2003 their DNS server.  If so, how are the network adapter settings configured on the Windows 7 machines?

On the server does it 'hold' the DNS record for the Windows 7 clients.

Are their problems with domain being not xyz, but xyz.local?

Comment: Guy, can you tell me a little more about the third problem? My domain is xyz.local. Thanks

Comment: Dear David
Just a matter of consistency.  Sometimes I forget to match the NIC Adapter, or the System Full Computer Name, with the DNS record.